# Backward representation of the general Markov process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

One usually deals with a discrete time Markov process in the following form: given a state space $E$ the Markov process is defined by transition kernel $T(B|x)$ such that
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_1\in B|X_0 = x) = T(B|x)
$$
for all $x\in E$, $B\in\mathcal{B}(E)$.

So, given a current state we have a distribution of the future state.

On the other hand it can be an interesting problem given a current state to find a distribution of the previous state which "fits" with a transition kernel $T$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equation

Comment: It's only for the continuous time.

Comment: As an aside note that your sentence *so given a state $X_{n+1}$ we know the distribution of $X_n$* is misleading because in the formula just above, $v_n$ is not independent on $X_{n+1}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you for this comment on independence.

Comment: So? You might care to correct this paragraph in your post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called time-reversal of Markov chains and is presented in numerous lecture notes available on the web, see [here](http://statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s19.pdf) for example.

**Remark** As said in the comments, the sentence of the post stating that *given a state $X_{n+1}$ we know the distribution of $X_n$* signals a deep misunderstanding of the structure of Markov processes. In the example considered, $v_n$ is not independent on $X_{n+1}$ and one should note that, given any nonzero $a$ and $b$ and any random $X$, *any random variable* $Y$ can be written as $Y=X/a-(b/a)V$ for a well chosen random variable $V$.